# Adding POS part-of-speech column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm working in pyspark dataframe where I want to add a column to see if the word is NOUN, VERB, ADJ, ADV, ADP, PROPN using pyspark or nltk.pos_tag

Here is the pyspark table.

```
------------------------
| event_dt   | words   |
------------------------
| 2020-09-02 | mifi    |
| 2020-09-02 | hotspot |
| 2020-09-03 | service |
| 2020-09-03 | word    |
| 2020-09-03 | plan    |
```

and both columns continues.

Here is the result I'm looking for using pyspark.

```
-------------------------------
| event_dt   | words   | pos  |
-------------------------------
| 2020-09-02 | mifi    | ADJ  |
| 2020-09-02 | hotspot | ADJ  |
| 2020-09-03 | service | ADJ  |
| 2020-09-03 | word    | NOUN |
| 2020-09-03 | plan    | NOUN |
```

I'm not sure where the words in column 'words' are being compared to get the result being ADJ, NOUN, PRONOUN etc.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this situation is to use **`when()`** **`otherwise()`** which is nothing but **`if else`**

**One pre-requisite : Just add all the words in a list**

## Create the dataframe here

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("2020-09-02","mifi"),("2020-09-02","hotspot"),("2020-09-02","service"),("2020-09-02","word"),("2020-09-02","plan")],["event_dt","word"])
df.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-------+
|event_dt  |word   |
+----------+-------+
|2020-09-02|mifi   |
|2020-09-02|hotspot|
|2020-09-02|service|
|2020-09-02|word   |
|2020-09-02|plan   |
+----------+-------+
```

## List of words whihc are adjective & when() otherwise() condition

```
adj = ["mifi", "hotspot","service"]
df = df.withColumn("pos", F.when(F.col("word").isin(adj), F.lit("ADJ")).otherwise(F.lit("NOUN")))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

## Final Output

```
+----------+-------+----+
|event_dt  |word   |pos |
+----------+-------+----+
|2020-09-02|mifi   |ADJ |
|2020-09-02|hotspot|ADJ |
|2020-09-02|service|ADJ |
|2020-09-02|word   |NOUN|
|2020-09-02|plan   |NOUN|
+----------+-------+----+
```

Comment: Thank you @dsk for the help. The issue is that there are around half a million rows of those 2 input columns. I cannot do createDataframe for such huge data by entering each word and either is ADJ or Noun etc.. In the example above the output column 'pos' was showing ADJ and Noun only but also need to find if word is Pronoun, Adverb etc. 
Is there any other way?